# adding node in D3.js on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to draw a graph similar to [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) with some additional functionality:

1. on click on a node it expands and show it's friends and
2. on click on the same node for a second time, it collapses.

On right-click I want to put custom menu on each node like delete, show details, etc.

Here's what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/AgfsaQue

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html)?

Comment: this graph work on parent child while i need which work independently